# TortoiseGit でコミットメッセージ編集時のスペルチェックを無効にしたい

Tags: tortoisegit

TortoiseGitでコミットするときにどのような修正なのかをメッセージとして書き残せますが、これに勝手に赤いアンダーラインが表示されます。
スペルチェッカーというらしいですが、これを非表示にしたいのですがどのような方法がありますでしょうか。

自分で調べたところ、TortoiseGitの設定のダイアログ2にずばりそのものの設定があるという情報がありました。
しかし私の最新のバージョンでそれは存在せず、どうやらダイアログ3になっていて、しかもどう設定してよいのか全くわかりません。
出てくる情報はこの「ダイアログ2」バージョンのものばっかりです。

また、windowsの設定でもすばりスペルチェックがあるということなのですが、これも私のwindows8では見当たりませんでした。

コミットする度に書きづらく見づらいのでなんとかしたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

設定画面で「ダイアログ3」を開いたら「設定のでどころ」で (よく分からなければ) システム または グローバル を選択し、すぐ下の「コミット」の言語で "(disable)" を選択して「OK」または「適用」をクリックしてダイアログを閉じます。

**設定ダイアログの例:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**確認環境:**
TortoiseGit 2.10.0.2